How set and get cross domain for local and session storage with selenium python?
I want to set local and session storage the site: "https:/example.org " and get them, one domain source will have - "web.op.org ", and the second one - "web.my_site.org "
I searched on stackoverflow, but found nothing in the questions

Selenium has methods for reading/writing cookies.  You need to be at the domain of the cookie to read or write for that domain.  (so URL bar should show "web.op.org" if you wanted to read those cookies or write cookies for that domain) https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/cookies/

I don't need to use cookies, I need to use local ans session storage

same same domain rules there... just execute script to get localStorage values if Selenium has no method for that.
